# Clean conversion from int list to character and then back to int list, in Python

Tags: python

I want to convert the list of Integers in Python into Characters,

Here is what I have done,

```
S = [55, 58, 5, 13, 14, 12, 22, 20, 70, 83, 90, 69, 84, 91, 80, 91]

D = ""
for i in S:
    D += chr(i)
D = ''.join(map(str, D))
```

This wouldn't work because the `chr` value of `13` is `\r` , it will return the start of the line and will cause the expulsion of first four values.

The output will be the character values for `14, 12, 22, 20, 70, 83, 90, 69, 84, 91, 80, 91` only (the first four values will be removed due to \r)

Here is the output,

```
♫♀▬¶FSZET[P[
```

So, It cannot be converted back to the original Integer value.

The second approach,

If i do this,

```
S = [55, 58, 5, 13, 14, 12, 22, 20, 70, 83, 90, 69, 84, 91, 80, 91]
print(repr( ", ".join(map(str, map(chr, S)))))
```

It works but it will output,

```
'7, :, \x05, \r, \x0e, \x0c, \x16, \x14, F, S, Z, E, T, [, P, ['
```

But, If i convert it back to integer using `ord` then each character will be converted separately including `x` `,` `\` etc....

```
D = repr( ", ".join(map(str, map(chr, S))))
for i in D:
    print(ord(i))
```

I want to convert the integer to the string and then back to the integers.
The final output should be the original integer List which was,

```
[55, 58, 5, 13, 14, 12, 22, 20, 70, 83, 90, 69, 84, 91, 80, 91]
```

How could I acheive this. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ast

string_version = str(S)
list_version = ast.literal_eval(string_version)
```

Also, the following works fine:

```
string_version = ''.join(chr(s) for s in S)
list_verison = list(ord(s) for s in string_version)
```

The `\r` does not remove the first four characters, it just makes it print that way to a terminal, and the string isn't very human-readable.

You can abbreviate a bit further if you want:

```
string_version = ''.join(map(chr, S))
list_version = list(map(ord, string_version))
```

The `\r` might cause a problem if you need to print the `string_version` to a terminal, then copy-paste it and read it back, or something like that. In that case you could do:

```
string_version = repr(''.join(map(chr, S)))
# print, copy, paste, etc.
list_version = list(map(ord, ast.literal_eval(string_version)))
```

It's a less readable form than my first code snippet, but it might be more compact.

Comment: It doesn't work either,
print(''.join(chr(s) for s in S)) outputs, ♫♀▬¶FSZET[P[

Comment: and string_version = str(S) printing the same list of integers without converting it to string

Comment: @Xufyan: Look at the result of `print(repr(''.join(chr(s) for s in S)))`. As I have already said, the four characters are there in the string, but the `\r` affects how it prints to a terminal.

Comment: @Xufyan: you are mistaken. `str(S)` is indeed a string. See for yourself by looking at the result of `print(type(str(S)))`. It happens to be the same string that `S` is converted to by `print` when you do `print(S)`.

Comment: hello, but if i write "♫♀▬¶FSZET[P[" to a file and then read it from file and convert it then it wont return the original integers

Comment: @Xufyan: It works when I do it. What code did you use to write to and read from the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `bytearray` here:

```
S = [55, 58, 5, 13, 14, 12, 22, 20, 70, 83, 90, 69, 84, 91, 80, 91]

as_str = str(bytearray(S))
print list(bytearray(as_str))
# [55, 58, 5, 13, 14, 12, 22, 20, 70, 83, 90, 69, 84, 91, 80, 91]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a list integers `s`, you can create the output string `d` with:

```
s = [...]
d = "".join(map(chr, [letter for letter in s]))
```

You can convert the string `d` back into a list with:

```
d = "..."
s = map(int, map(ord, list(d)))
```